What are the requirements for the beta badge?
What are the requirements for the beta badge? I know that I have to actively participate in the private beta. What does actively mean? Is there a minimum number of questions, etc?

Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81833/when-do-i-earn-the-beta-badge

Beta badges are in! http://bricks.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta Yay, got one.

A full list of badges can be found on Meta.SE
The user must earn at least three bronze badges during the private beta period. The badge will be awarded when we move into public beta.

It's exactly the same answer

http://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/105/tim - only 2 bronze and a beta badge.

Since the answer isn't really given elsewhere, on purpose, I'll chime in with what I remember being told when commiting to another beta: one must at least post 10 answers and/or questions for the commitment to be considere fullfilled.
I don't know if it's correct or applies to he beta badge, and I wouldn't bother too much. More participating and less worrying should get the job done.

Yep, the fact that badges are awarded slightly opaquely is discussed on podcast 23 (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/se-podcast-23/) where "mystery" is considered one of the six tenets of games, and they want the badges to be "mysterious", where you have to puzzle out how to earn them. Otherwise it's not fun ;)

This applies to the area 51 commitment, but the Beta badge is easier to get than this.

I knew I answered too much
